# How to copy an executing script from current folder to another by double click

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

How should we copy an executing script from one folder to the another?

The script content is:

```
#!/bin/sh

zenity --forms --title="Add Friend" \
    --text="Enter information about your friend." \
    --separator="," \
    --add-entry="First Name" \
    --add-entry="Family Name" \
    --add-entry="Email" \
    --add-calendar="Birthday" >> addr.csv

case $? in
    0)
        echo "Friend added.";;
    1)
        echo "No friend added."
    ;;
    -1)
        echo "An unexpected error has occurred."
    ;;
esac
```

Lets say i have saved the above script as `test.sh` in `home/user/Documents/sh/` and when I execute **test.sh** by double click it should copy itself to the `meow` folder `home/user/wow/meow/`.

Comment: Add a line at the end of script? `cp /path/to/source /path/to/destination`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, but you can handle this slightly more elegantly than a raw copy.

```
mkdir -p $HOME/wow/meow
cp "$(readlink -f $0)" "$HOME/wow/meow"
```

- It's using `$HOME` so we aren't reliant on a hard-coded path (moderately more reliable than the `~` substitution for scripting).
- We check that the target directory exists (and create it if not).
- We get the actual script location rather than relying on a hard-coded path.

Answer (score 2):

Add a line in the script to copy itself:

```
cp /home/user/Documents/sh/test.sh home/user/wow/meow/
```

Comment: yeah, like this I mean..:)